# Errors were encountered while processing

Tags: sudo

When trying to do `sudo apt-get install` I'm getting this at the end:

```
Processing triggers for python-central ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 logmein-client:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How do I get rid of this error.

Comment: What were you trying to install originally?

Comment: Anything, this shows up

Comment: Execute this command: `sudo dpkg -r logmein-client;
sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: What does that command do? Am I right in thinking it uninstalls the package and then tries to reinstall it?